# GeoJSON - Obtain linestrings inside a given bounding box

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have two layers in an Argentinian railroad-related project: one is for train stations and the other is for railroad lines. The first one has about 1100 points and the second, about 250 finely-detailed linestrings. I use leaflet.js as my framework, and a Bing layer and a background satellite imagery.

Right now, I have a web application in which I charge straight into memory both GeoJSON files, and it works just OK, except when I need to zoom or pan to a specific feature: it works really slow. I tried removing almost all the features, leaving just two or three linestrings and a couple dozen stations, and it works fast enough to be usable. So, I guess I need to refactor my code so every time I pan or zoom the map, there's an Ajax query to a PHP script that filters my layers using a bounding box query.

It is trivial to filter train stations because they are just points. My problem arises when I need to filter railroad lines: as I said, they are finely drawn, so each one of them has hundreds if not thousands of points. I tried a "foreach" loop with a coordinate query inside, but it takes forever to iterate and filter every coordinate that falls outside the bounding box. So, my question is: is there any way to make this more effective, or at least less CPU-intensive? I need to return a geojson object containing trimmed lines that fit nicely into the provided bounding box.

Edit: please bear with me, as I am an absolute amateur on this subject.

Edit 2: to summarize what I'm trying to achieve: I need to filter a GeoJSON object containing linestrings to return a sub-set of linestrings that fit inside a given bounding box, trimming those linestrings that are bigger than it.

Edit 3: forgot to mention that simplified geometries aren't a valid solution for me, as I need the current level of detail for railroad routes.

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid for displaying big GeoJSON files simplifying the geometries along the way (via https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt), and https://turfjs.org/docs/ for manual geoprocessing.

Comment: While I forgot to mention that simplifying geometries is out of the question, the transforming bboxClip method can be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, using your suggestion, I ended up finding a similar method in Leaflet: clipSegment, so I guess I'll end up using that. Thanks again!

Comment: I still think you should give VectorGrid.Slicer a try, because your ultimate goal is smooth map panning/zooming, not clipping lines (and you're missing the fact that `geojson-vt` geometry simplification happens on a per-zoom-level basis instead of globally). See also the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I read about VectorGrid and, after some additional research, it did work! Thanks @IvanSanchez!